# Custom views relationship

Tags: 7, views

I have a problem with a pretty complex custom views relationship.

The scenario:

I have nodes that have a field field_revision. This field has the same value for nodes that belong to the same revision. I have another field field_element. This field stores information for some container the node is assigned to.

What I want now is a views relationship that gives me the possibility to get all nodes of the same revision assigned to a specific container. My idea is to use the SQL joins as follows:

1. node.nid > field_data_field_revision.entity_id
2. field_data_field_revision.field_revision_value > field_data_field_revision.field_revision_value
3. field_data_field_revision.entity_id > node.nid
4. node.nid > field_data_field_element.entity_id with extra field_data_field_element.field_element_value = 123 (defined by a filter)

The joins look like this:

```
$join2 = new views_join;
$join2->construct('field_data_field_revision', $join1_name, 'field_revision_value', 'field_revision_value', NULL, 'INNER');
```

I managed to implement that using the views API and its working fine with..

..one problem:

Whenever I use the relationship I lose all the table rows of the view with nodes from revisions that do not have other nodes in the container I want to join to. I tried to use left joins but I did not get the expected result.

Did anyone of you ever try something like this and has another approach or an idea what I may change to not lose rows when there are no results?

Thanks, j

Comment: Hint: See the SQL generated. Paste it directly into something like PHPMyAdmin. Play with it until it returns what you want to. Backport it to Views. If you can't backport, at least share "before - after" SQL queries with us. For me, this is the approach that usually helps./

Comment: I will try again. Did not touch that for a long time. I used to have solved that in MS SQL with some fancy "full outer join"s but I will give it another try. Thanks!